# On which phones/Android version can Google Cardboard work?

Tags: android, mobile-phones, google-cardboard

Can the software for Google Cardboard work with any Android phone, or just with a few specific models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some data can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started)

**Developing**
Developing Google Cardboard apps requires

- Android studio 1.0 or higher
- Android SDK 19 or higher

**Running**
Running Google Cardboard apps on physical devices requires

- A device running Jellybean or higher (android 16, 4.1.x+)
- A device with support for *at least* OpenGL 2.0. Luckily, as [this chart over at Google's developer page](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL) states that 100% of the devices support at least 2.0

The example project at [Cardboard getting started](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started) also requires NFC, but I'm unsure if this is required for any Cardboard app, or just for that example.

So, to answer your question, no Cardboard will not just work with *any* phone, but since Jellybean+ is about 90% of all devices, you'll reach a fair share.

Comment: NFC is good to have.. Its only required to start the application automatically. This can be done manually too. So NFC is not mandatory.

Comment: @Pietro You NEED a gyro sensor and an accelerometer. Most phones have the second one, not so many the first one. For example, my LG Fino does not have a gyroscope and does not work with google cardboard.

Comment: Android Studio isn't a requirement, one can develop with Unity (for instances).

Answer (score 2):

According to the official site, it seems like the requirements on the phones are:

- running Android 16 (Jelly Bean) or higher
- OpenGL ES 2.0. `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />`
- some kind of gyro sensor (probably)

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started#before_you_begin